# I got ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) with the command sudo mysql on ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, lamp, apache2.4, ubuntu-20.04

I am really a noob in all this stuff like php or sql so I took a coursera course where they told us to install LAMP.

I have Linux and Apache2 but for MySql, I followed this tutorial [how to install LAMP](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04). I followed it and after the place where we have to run `sudo mysql`, I got `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. but according to the tutorial I should get:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 22
Server version: 8.0.19-0ubuntu5 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Please can anybody help me with this as soon as possible because the course I am doing has a deadline. Also if any documentation available on the web, please share.

if you need some more information on the error, please tell me and also how to extract them.

Thank you.

**EDIT**: my problem was solved and I was able to enter the password after I ran `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: You need to enter your root password. You should have been asked to create one during the mysql installation

Comment: I was not prompted any area in the terminal where I could enter the password.  However when I ran mysql -u root -p, I was able to enter the password and solve the problem

Comment: This answer solved completely it for me : https://askubuntu.com/a/784347

Comment: This answer solved it 100% for me for this same problem : https://askubuntu.com/a/784347

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try below commands in your mysql console

```
mysql>  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql>  ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but my problem was that I wan not able to enter the CLI, no area where I could enter the password was there. However my problem was solved and I was able to enter the password after I ran mysql -u root -p.